# Не удаётся удалить класс в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
/* Добавляется класс для появления формы */
$(".form").click(function() {
  $(".form").addClass("active")
});
/* Добавляется id */
$('.close-btn').click(function() {
  $('.form').removeClass('active');
  $('.form').attr('id', 'close');
});
```

```css
.form.active {
  padding: 24px;
  background: #6c4a27;
  border: 6px solid #cb9a4b;
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 20px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  height: 450px;
  -webkit-animation: openForm 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
  animation: openForm 1.4s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
}

.form h1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.active h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.form.active * {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.form.active::after,
.form.active::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

input,
textarea {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fefefe;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
}

input {
  top: 0;
}

input:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.5s 1s ease;
}

input:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.7s 1s ease;
}

textarea {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.9s 1s ease;
}

h1 {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #cb9a4b;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease;
}

.form {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #6c4a27;
  border: 6px solid #cb9a4b;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.form .btn-xl {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.form::before,
.form::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9999, 0.9999);
  transform: scale(0.9999, 0.9999);
}

.form::before {
  top: 15px;
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  border-top: 11px solid #fff;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
}

.form::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 11px solid #fff;
  border-left: 16px solid #fff;
}

.form:hover::before {
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

@-moz-keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .form {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide-own {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #etc {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #del {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.form .form-control {
  background: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  height: 70px !important;
}

.date {
  line-height: 18px !important;
}

.form h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form .btn {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 45.2px;
}

.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.form#close {
  -webkit-animation: closeForm 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
  animation: closeForm 1.4s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
}

@-moz-keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}

@keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Форма -->
<div class="form">
  <i class="fa fa-times close-btn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h1>Форма записи</h1>
  <form action="mail/little_me.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ф.И.О." required data-validation-required-message="Пожалуйста, заполните это поле!" name="name_little" id="name_little" />
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" required data-validation-required-message="Пожалуйста, введите свой номер!" name="phone_little" id="phone_little" />
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Курс" required data-validation-required-message="Выберите курс!" name="curs_little" id="curs_little" />
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="email" class="date" required data-validation-required-message="Пожалуйста, напишите почту!" name="email_little" id="email_little" placeholder="Почта">
    </div>
    <div class="success"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-down btn btn-xl" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-label">Отправить</span>
        </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

UPD: Добавил CSS, дабы была более понятна ситуация. Надо развернуть на полный экран.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происходит это, потому что при клике на `.close-btn` вы удаляете класс и в этот же момент его добавляете, так как `.close-btn` находится внутри `.form`, на клике на которую уже прописано добавление класса. Для раскрытия формы лучше добавьте новую кнопку и вешайте событие именно на нее.

```js
/* Добавляется класс для появления формы */
$('.open-btn').click(function() {
  $('.form').addClass('active')
});
/* Добавляется id */
$('.close-btn').click(function() {
  $('.form').removeClass('active');
  $('.form').attr('id', 'close');
});
```

```css
.form.active {
  padding: 24px;
  background: #6c4a27;
  border: 6px solid #cb9a4b;
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 20px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  height: 450px;
  -webkit-animation: openForm 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
  animation: openForm 1.4s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
}

.form h1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.active h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.form.active * {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.form.active::after,
.form.active::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

input,
textarea {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fefefe;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
}

input {
  top: 0;
}

input:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.5s 1s ease;
}

input:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.7s 1s ease;
}

textarea {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.9s 1s ease;
}

h1 {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #cb9a4b;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease;
}

.form {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #6c4a27;
  border: 6px solid #cb9a4b;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.form .btn-xl {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.form::before,
.form::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9999, 0.9999);
  transform: scale(0.9999, 0.9999);
}

.form::before {
  top: 15px;
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  border-top: 11px solid #fff;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
}

.form::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 11px solid #fff;
  border-left: 16px solid #fff;
}

.form:hover::before {
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

@-moz-keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}

@keyframes openForm {
  0% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
}


/*@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .form {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide-own {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #etc {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #del {
    display: none !important;
  }
}*/

.form .form-control {
  background: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  height: 70px !important;
}

.date {
  line-height: 18px !important;
}

.form h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form .btn {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 45.2px;
}

.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #f00;
  display: none;
}

.open-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #000;
}

.form.active .close-btn {
  display: block;
}

.form.active .open-btn {
  display: none;
}

.form#close {
  -webkit-animation: closeForm 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
  animation: closeForm 1.4s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9);
}

@-moz-keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}

@keyframes closeForm {
  0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Форма -->
<div class="form">
  <i class="fa fa-times open-btn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-times close-btn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h1>Форма записи</h1>
  <form action="mail/little_me.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ф.И.О." required data-validation-required-message="Пожалуйста, заполните это поле!" name="name_little" id="name_little" />
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" required data-validation-required-message="Пожалуйста, введите свой номер!" name="phone_little" id="phone_little" />
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Курс" required data-validation-required-message="Выберите курс!" name="curs_little" id="curs_little" />
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="email" class="date" required data-validation-required-message="Пожалуйста, напишите почту!" name="email_little" id="email_little" placeholder="Почта">
    </div>
    <div class="success"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-down btn btn-xl" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-paint"></span>
          <span class="btn-label">Отправить</span>
        </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: добавил CSS. Посмотри, ибо с ним картина более ясна

Comment: @Кенан нет там никакого css

Comment: теперь CSS на месте

Answer (score 3):

Не удаётся удалить класс в jquery? Его удается удалить, но он же сразу добавляется обратно. Ты повесил обработчик события "Клик" на родительский элемент, и потом вешаешь еще один дочерний. В результате срабатывают сразу два обработчика, так как элемент с классом '.close-btn' вложен в элемент с классом '.form'.

Answer (score 1):

По мимо `addClass` и `removeClass` есть еще `attr`. Я часто не хочу заморачиваться и просто делаю:

```
$(object).attr("class", "myClass");
```

Этот способ работает безотказно :)